# Ошибка конфигурации FindByIndexNameSessionRepository "RedisConnectionFactory is required"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, redis

Реализовывая логику лимитирования активных сессий для каждого пользователя (кол-во сессий хранится в бд, а сами сессии в Redis), наткнулся на проблему конфигурирования `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`.

Из-за того, что я инжекчу `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository` spring начинает конфигурировать бин в классе [RedisHttpSessionConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.html), при этом не заинжектив в себя поля через сеттеры.

По итогу получаю ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(RedisAccessor.java:38) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet(RedisTemplate.java:127) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.createRedisTemplate(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:291) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.sessionRepository(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:120) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Код конфига:

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository sessionRepository;    
    // ....

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            // ....
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new CustomAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry(), sessionsLimitRepository));
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry(sessionRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration("server", 6379));
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
   }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- .... -->
</dependencies>
```

Если убрать\закомментировать места где используется `FindByIndexNameSessionRepository`, то сеттеры [RedisHttpSessionConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/api/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.html), вызываются "кишками" спринга в момент создания бина `springSessionRepositoryFilter`.

Если я правильно понял, то я, случайно, сломал порядок конфигурирования бинов. В попытках это починить, пробовал `@DependsOn`, `@Lazy` и различные махинации с перемещением бинов в разные классы конфигов, сменой порядка загрузки конфигов и прочее.

UPD 1: Добавил бин `httpSessionEventPublisher`
UPD 2: Добавил pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема была в том, что spring-boot конфигурировал уже большую часть бинов за меня.

Для решения данной проблемы необходимо удалить `@EnableRedisHttpSession` (`@EnableWebSecurity` тоже можно удалить), бины `redisConnectionFactory` и `httpSessionEventPublisher`, и по желанию можно удалить ненужную зависимость `spring-session-core`

Актуальный код конфига:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<? extends Session> sessionRepository;

    // ....

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            // ....
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new CustomAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry(), sessionsLimitRepository));
}

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(sessionRepository);
    }

}
```

Актуальный pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- .... -->
</dependencies>
```